# Issues with dynamic django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm writing a program to manage a database of electronic components. The user needs to be able to organize components into groups. Each group has a different set of fields (resistors are different from capacitors, etc), though some are common. I also want the user to be able to create new groups and specify the particular fields for that group. Instead of dealing with truly dynamic fields, here's what I've come up with:

Here are the relevant models:

```
class ComponentGroup(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   code = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)

class GroupField(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   group = models.ForeignKey(ComponentGroup, related_name='fields')

class Part(models.Model):
   group = models.ForeignKey(ComponentGroup)
   fields = models.ManyToManyField(GroupField, through='Parameter')
   # ... some "static" fields

class Parameter(models.Model):
   field = models.ForeignKey(GroupField)
   part = models.ForeignKey(Part)

   value = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ParameterForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Parameter
      fields = ('value',)

class PartForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Part
      exclude = ('fields', 'group')
```

So any given group has a set of `GroupField`s, each of which has a name. A `Parameter` specifies a value for a specific `Part` that corresponds to a `GroupField` in the `ComponentGroup` that the `Part` is a member of.

I'm trying to create a way for the user to create a new `Part` from a given group. I *think* the "django way" to approach this is using a formset. Is that right? What is the "right" way to handle this?

Edit

Here's the view I've written to generate the form for the "static" fields and the formset for the fields specified by the `ComponentGroup`, but it has several problems -- see comments. I'm not sure how to work around them. Any advice?

```
def part_add(request, code):
   thisgroup = get_object_or_404(ComponentGroup, code=code)
   thispart = Part()
   thispart.group = thisgroup
   thispart.save() ### don't want to do this here, but sort of need to to generate ID
                   # creates the problem that if form is not submitted, now have a 
                   # completely blank Part 

   for field in thisgroup.fields.all():
      p = Parameter()
      p.field = field
      p.part = thispart
      p.save() # would like to save the parameters at the same time as the Part is saved,
               # when the form is submitted but if they're not saved, they will not show 
               # up on the formset


   ParametersInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(CEIPart, Parameter, form=ParameterForm, extra=0, can_delete=False)

   if request.POST:
      form = PartForm(request.POST, group=thisgroup, instance=thispart)
      formset = ParametersInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=thispart)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
      if formset.is_valid():
         formset.save()

      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ceiparts.views.part_detail', args = (thispart.CEIPN,)))
   else:
      form = PartForm(group=thisgroup, instance=thispart)
      formset = ParametersInlineFormset(instance=thispart)

   return render(request, 'ceiparts/ceiparts_add.html',
 { 'form' : form,
    'formset' : formset,
    'ceipart' : thispart,
    'componentgroup' : thisgroup }
 )
```

Comment: The lazy way would be to have a separate view for creating new parts.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? That's what i was trying to do with `part_add`